# elasticsearch query with some conditions

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation, elasticsearch-aggregation

let's say there are 3 fields C,D,E.  C is some task ID, and D is timestamp. E is a flag, value of E is either null or "finished".

Is there a query to search this:
the newest record for every different taskID, then, keep the ones that have null for value of E.

```
for example:

id:1, time:1, E:null
id:1, time:2, E:null
id:1, time:3, E:"finished"
id:2, time:1, E:null
id:2, time:2, E:null
id:2, time:3, E:null
id:3, time:1, E:null
id:3, time:2, E:null

the searched results should be line 6 and line 8
```

I am not sure how to do add fiters for this problem. Could anyone help?

Comment: provide some documents and the expected result.

Comment: @rabbitbr thank you for response, I just edited the question with an example. wish the problem is more clear this time.